# Gitlab-CI and Apartment Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, apartment-gem

I'm experiencing a strange problem while trying to set up Gitlab CI on my `Rails 5.1` project which uses `apartment` gem for multitennancy support.
I've got docker-compose set up to build my containers and run tests. And they are passing on my local machine, but Gitlab pipelines keep failing with this error.

```
$ bundle exec rspec
/builds/demiurge/new_world/spec/models/char/skill_spec.rb:5: warning: toplevel constant Skill referenced by Char::Skill
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: Apartment::Tenant.create slug

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
  : SET search_path TO "public", "shared_extensions"
# ./app/models/world.rb:36:in `create_tenant'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# PG::UndefinedObject:
#   ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
#   LINE 1: ...har_id" integer, "type" character varying, "data" hstore, "p...
#                                                                ^
#   ./db/schema.rb:292:in `block in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.58676 seconds (files took 5 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

My docker-compose setup is simple:

```
cache:
 image: redis:alpine
 ports:
   - 6379:6379

db:
 image: postgres:9.6-alpine
 volumes:
   - ./data/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 ports:
   - 5432:5432
```

And my gilab-ci.yml looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/almaron/cbb0f987988c082e2f34565f98b01b71). And I also have a `lib/tasks/apartment.rake` task set up like [this](https://gist.github.com/almaron/31cd181e6fb1c03ddb15633a80a05543) that is supposed to enable hstore on DB creation. The task passes on CI, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` please ?

Answer (score -2):

`ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist` This error tells you that the `hstore` extension is not present on your postgres database.
You have to enable it in a migration before using this datatype anywhere.

```
def change
  enable_extension "hstore"
end
```

You have to ensure that the database user is a `superuser`

Comment: I have it in the apartment.rake task I linked to in the question.

Comment: Why did you use a rake task instead of enabling `hstore` in a migration ?

Comment: 1. Because the gem docs suggested this aproach. 2. Because it seemed reasonable to make it part of the `db:create` process then a migration.

Comment: Since Rails 4 the method `enable_extension` is the recommended way to do that. Sometime you may not use `db:create` but instead directly `db:migrate` or `db:schema:load` and in this case you won't have your extension enabled.